# jQuery how to hide drop down when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a mobile nav for my portfolio. I want everything but the top to be hidden when first loaded. The broken image on the left is my logo, and on the right is the shutter button that drops everything down. Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/wesleyjoseph/pen/OMwMjG). I need the drop-down to be hidden on page load.

```
<nav class="nav-main">

        <div class="handle">

        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/logos/navlogo.png" width="40" height="40"></a>

        <img src="images/logos/menu.png" width="40" height="40" class="menu">

        </div>




        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-drop">Gallery</a>
                <div class="nav-content">
                    <div class="nav-sub">
                        <ul class="showing">
                            <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dreamweaver</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Premiere</a></li>
                        </ul>                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item">About</a>
            </li>



            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Are you just looking for the `.hide()` function in jQuery?

Comment: best way is to hide using css, and display using jQuery.

Comment: its already working https://jsfiddle.net/x0kLmtpp/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('ul').hide();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
var par = $('p');
$(par).hide();
```

to:

```
var par = $('.nav-main > ul');
$(par).hide();
```

Comment: $('p'); 
------------------------->
    $('.nav-main > ul');


P.s: Open Codepen